# Express always sends req.files for input file type even when it's empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an input field like:

`input(type='file', id='avatar', name='avatar', class='fivecol', accept='image/*')`

and in my controller I check for `req.files.avatar`... Even when it's empty, the output still is logged and it temporarily stores (something) in `/uploads`.

Here is a console log of `req.files.avatar`

```
{ avatar:
   { domain: null,
     _events: null,
     _maxListeners: 10,
     size: 0,
     path: 'uploads/aa7571f48cc1d0a3d1242d737f8c5fa0',
     name: '',
     type: 'application/octet-stream',
     hash: false,
     lastModifiedDate: null,
     _writeStream:
      { domain: null,
        _events: null,
        _maxListeners: 10,
        path: 'uploads/aa7571f48cc1d0a3d1242d737f8c5fa0',
        fd: 21,
        writable: false,
        flags: 'w',
        encoding: 'binary',
        mode: 438,
        bytesWritten: 0,
        busy: false,
        _queue: [],
        _open: [Function] },
     length: [Getter],
     filename: [Getter],
     mime: [Getter] } }
```

Why is it doing this? Also, there is a file that is `0 bytes` in that `/uploads` folder named `aa7571f48cc1d0a3d1242d737f8c5fa0` (or whatever other random hash gets generated each time).

Additionally, why isn't express clearing those temporarily uploaded files out of `/uploads`?

Comment: Does it produce the files if you *don't* check `req.files.avatar`?

Comment: and, does your form have the attribute `enctype='multipart/form-data'`?

Comment: Yes it has the `multipart/form-data` within the form, I'm already using it to successfully resize images/push to my CDN. Not sure how checking for `req.files.avatar` would have an effect, because in any case, I need to check `req.files.avatar.size` to see if it's empty or not before I decide to resize.

Comment: Hmm what a pain. The sloppy and easy solution would be to just delete the temporary file yourself, if the length is zero, using code similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/17862458/1380669