# Cleaning temporary files after file upload with restify

Tags: node.js, restify, formidable

I am building a node storage server with `restify`. I am processing uploads via `restify.bodyParser`, which under the hood uses `formidable`.

Formidable stores files in `os.tmpDir()` by default, and I need to change that to some other folder, and so I did via `restify.bodyParser({uploadDir: '/path/to/new/tmp'})`.

The problem is that those temporary files are kept in the tmp directory even after I finish processing the request.

I have seen this question ([Handling Temporary Files after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843806/handling-temporary-files-after-upload)), that supposes to just delete the tmp file after processing it.

My question is, do you need to always manually remove the file? Even with the default `os.tmpDir()` directory? How does the default system tmp folder work? Does it flush itself sometimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, for file uploads, your code moves the uploaded file from its temporary location to a more permanent location. If, after processing the upload, you are left with a temporary file, you are supposed to clean it up manually (using `fs.unlink()`).

On UNIX-type operating systems, `os.tmpDir()` (which is usually `/tmp`) isn't cleaned up periodically by the system (although it is typically cleared during system boot).

Comment: Yeah I am using chunked upload, so I use streams to copy the contents of the chunk to resulting file, I forgot to mention that. So generally I would use `fs.rename` to move the file to new location, but as I use streams, I need to remove the temp file manually when I finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a single file, or all files

```
import rimraf from 'rimraf';
import fs from 'fs';

export class DiskCleaner {
  constructor(public folderName: string) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, DiskCleaner.prototype);
  }

  removeDirectory(): void {
    try {
      rimraf(this.folderName, function () {});
    } catch (error) {}
  }
  unlinkFile(path: string): void {
    fs.unlinkSync(path);
  }
}
```